# How to make the hover smooth?

Tags: html, css

```
.proposal p{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #494949;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  line-height: 20px;
  max-height: 100px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}

.proposal:hover p{
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here I've applied hover on a paragraph to reveal rest of its hidden content, how can I make the animation smooth?

Comment: You can use the `animation-duration` attribute in css: https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp

Comment: use `transition: all ease-in-out 0.4s;` make working smoothly .

Answer (score 3):

This is one way to do it with just CSS. Unfortunately the overflow property can't naturally be animated, so you have to use a mixture of tricks to achieve the desired effect. Here, we are animating margin, padding, and font size to fake the effect.

```css
.proposal {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px;
}

.proposal h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.proposal p {
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s, font-size .5s .25s, margin .5s .25s, padding .5s .25s;
}

.proposal:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 12px 0 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: font-size .25s, margin .25s, padding .25s, opacity .5s .25s;
}
```

```html
<div class="proposal">
  <h3>Hover me</h3>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et pulvinar quam. Integer ut mauris non mi malesuada fringilla. Quisque mattis, ante eu posuere facilisis, sem libero vehicula libero, tincidunt aliquet ante ligula et nisi. Pellentesque nec
    facilisis orci. Nunc sagittis purus ut eros efficitur pharetra. Nunc fermentum enim id lectus commodo, non luctus tortor finibus. Aliquam mauris tellus, vestibulum sed lacus auctor, suscipit commodo lacus. Aliquam nunc tortor, gravida in est bibendum,
    varius accumsan massa. Phasellus ultricies arcu ipsum, eu tempus ante vehicula sed.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `transition: overflow 0.5s linear;` somewhere inside `.proposal p {}`.

`overflow` will be the attribute that is getting affected.  I'm not exactly sure if that is the attribute you want to adjust but you can change that as needed.

`0.5s` means that the transition will last half a second.  Change as needed.

`linear` means that the animation will have the same speed throughout the animation.  There is also `ease` and others that you can use but I don't think it makes much of a difference when the animation is half a second long.

Add `-webkit-`, `-moz-`, etc, as needed.